# Why do we need DFS or BFS algorithms for graphs?

Tags: c, list, graph, traversal

[image]

I used list implementation to create a graph. However, I don't get why we need to perform a breath-first with queue or depth-first with stack to reach all nodes because when we use this implementation, we can reach all nodes.

For example, in this photo, I can do that

```
struct Node* temp = A;
while(temp != NULL)
{
 //do something
 temp = temp->next;
}
```

Comment: That loop *is* a "traversal" of the list.

Comment: Reaching all nodes *is* a traversal. Some are more efficient for particular graphs, others provide useful properties on the order in which you traverse things, etc.

Comment: I know but I mean there are depth first traversal with stack or breath-first traversal with queue. Why do we need these? @some-programmer-dude

Comment: Because you want to visit the nodes in different order? For what you seem to be doing (working with vertex and adjacency lists) a simple traversal algorithm might be enough, but for other graphs and tree-like structure, other use-cases need other algorithms. Remember, it's the *use-case* that decides the data-structure and algorithms to use, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a BFS or DFS search to visit all nodes of a graph. Those are *tree* traversal algorithms. If your graph isn't (just) stored as a tree, you wouldn't use an algorithm to visit it like a tree.

---

As an aside, your approach is a BFS and a DFS! A linked list is really just a unary tree, and the approach you describe performs both a DFS and BFS of it.